# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException when using JsonFilter

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am using Jave Spring Boot frame work. There are one Entity named "Reader" and one resouce for REST APIs. My goal is to use JsonFilter to dynamically filter out some specific fields(e.g. only keeping the `id` field in example) when using APIs. When I tried to retrieve the Reader class without appliying any filters, this error came up.

**Reader class:**

```
package book.demo.java.reader;
 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
 
@Entity
@JsonFilter("ReaderFilter")
public class Reader {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private int id;
    @Size(min=2)
    private String firstName;
    @Size(min=2)
    private String lastName;
    @Size(min=5)
    private String username;
    private String address;
 
    protected Reader() {}
 
    public Reader(String firstName, String lastName, String username, String address) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.username = username;
        this.address = address;
    }
 
    /*
 
    Getters and Setters...
 
    */
}
```

**Reader Resource:**

```
package book.demo.java.reader;
 
import book.demo.java.exception.ReaderNotFoundException;
import book.demo.java.jpa.ReaderRepository;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
 
@RestController
public class ReaderJpaResource {
 
    private final ReaderRepository repository;
 
    public ReaderJpaResource(ReaderRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
 
 
    
    @GetMapping("/jpa/reader/v1")
    public MappingJacksonValue retrieveAllReadersV1() {
        List<Reader> savedReader = repository.findAll();
        MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(savedReader);
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAll();
        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("ReaderFilter", filter);
        mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filters);
        return mappingJacksonValue;
    }
 
    @GetMapping("/jpa/reader/v2")
    public List<Reader> retrieveAllReadersV2() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
 
    @PostMapping("/jpa/reader")
    public MappingJacksonValue createReader(@Valid @RequestBody Reader reader) {
        Reader savedReader = repository.save(reader);
        MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(savedReader);
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("id");
        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("ReaderFilter", filter);
        mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filters);
 
        // a mappingJacksonValue that contains only the id
        return mappingJacksonValue;
    }
 
 
    @GetMapping("/jpa/reader/{id}")
    public Optional<Reader> retrieveReader(@PathVariable int id) {
        Optional<Reader> reader = repository.findById(id);
 
        if (reader.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ReaderNotFoundException("id: "+ id);
        }
        return reader;
    }
 
    @DeleteMapping("/jpa/reader/{id}")
    public void deleteReader(@PathVariable int id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
 
 
}
```

When I tried to send a GET request (two versions above). V1 works as expected. But if I use V2 (do not want to use any filter-related methods), it is shown as below.
[image]

**Complete Error Message in localhost page:**

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Type definition error: [simple type, class book.demo.java.reader.Reader]
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class book.demo.java.reader.Reader]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:489)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:297)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot resolve PropertyFilter with id 'ReaderFilter'; no FilterProvider configured (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1306)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:408)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.findPropertyFilter(StdSerializer.java:426)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFieldsFiltered(BeanSerializerBase.java:814)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:176)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1568)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1061)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:483)
    ... 48 more
```

So my question is, if the @JsonFilter is applied, do I need to involve MappingJac.ksonValue objects etc. in every REST API (findAll, findById, DeleteById, ..., etc)? What is a better way to solve this)? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on the @RequestBody to implicitly have the variables but here is an example of the @JsonView where you could accomplish the task easily
https://github.com/martypitt/JsonViewExample